# How to get dummy socket's id in socket.io server side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I would like to build some AI players for my game and I don't want to build sockets on the client side/ browser. So I use `socket.io-client` library and create some dummy sockets. I also want to keep track of their ids on the server side once I generate them.

```
const bots = {};
const client = require('socket.io-client');
const socket = client('http://localhost:8881');
const username = 'I am a bot';
bots[socket.id] = socket;
socket.emit('start', {username});
```

However this line `client('http://localhost:8881')` doesn't return a socket with **`id`** property, which means I couldn't build an dictionary of sockets to look up by their ids. Any other way to get the id once I generate the dummy socket?

Comment: You probably need to wait for the socket to finish connecting before trying to access the socket ID. I can't seem to load the [documentation](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/) for the client... but after waiting for the connect event you should be able to get the socket id and just send it over the socket connection to the server.

Comment: @SunilD. Thanks I think I have to send the ids from the client side if that's the case.